# Nodejs Installation

Tags: 12.04, nodejs

I have installed node.js and the version is 0.6.12.
I am trying to update it but the efforts are in vain. Even though i have installed the latest version the Terminal still shows the version as 0.6.12 which means that the installation is not successful. Please help . The screen shot:

[image: Terminal screenshot showing NodeJS v0.10.28 installed, v0.6.12 running]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **-g** flag to install nodejs globally eg:

```
sudo n stable -g
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install Node.js 0.10.28 in Ubuntu 12.04 by using tha repository [**ppa:chris-lea/node.js**](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

There is a package manager for Node.js in Main Ubuntu repository called NPM. Using this package manager you can install Node.js

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```